# Atmel Studio 7 Not Recognizing C++ STL Methods

Tags: c++, stl, atmel, atmelstudio

I'm writing some code in C++ with Atmel Studio 7 (for a SAMB11 if it matters), and it doesn't fully recognize the STL methods.  For example, the `vector`.  It recognizes the methods that are a part of the iterator template, such as `const_iterator`, but not the vector methods such as `push_back`.  It doesn't suggest them to autocomplete, and it underlines them with a red squiggly.  It compiles fine though.

Anybody know how to fix this?  Am I just missing a setting somewhere?